# Game loop - cause exception

Tags: graphics, 2d-games, game-loop

I have some problem. I am learning to program games and I want to try to program some game on my own. But I hit a snag just at beginning. I have 2 classes. The main class (call Frame) is only for create game frame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
        /**
         *
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Game game;
        public Frame() {
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                game = new Game();
                this.add(game.canvas);
                this.pack();
                this.setResizable(false);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                new Frame().setVisible(true);;
                        }
                });
        }

}
```

It goes correctly. But I have created a second class (call Game), that is supposed to provide game loop:

```
public class Game implements Runnable{
        public Canvas canvas;
        Thread thread;
        BufferStrategy bs;
        Graphics g;


        //Variables for game loop
        private int fps, timePerTick;
        double now, lastTime;
        private double delta;

        Game(){
                initVariables();
                canvas = new Canvas();
                canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }
        private void initVariables(){

                //create and start thread
                thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();
        }
        private void tick(){
        }
        private void render(){
                bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
                if (bs == null){
                        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
                        return;
                }
                g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
                g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
                bs.show();
                g.dispose();

        }
        private void initRun(){
                delta = 0;
                lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                fps = 30;
                timePerTick = 1000000000/fps;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
                initRun();
                int timer=0;
                int ticks=0;
                while(true){

                        now = System.nanoTime();
                        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
                        timer += (now - lastTime);
                        lastTime = now;
                        if(delta>=1){
                                tick();
                                render();
                                delta--;
                                ticks++;
                        }
                        if (timer>1000000000){
                                System.out.println("FPS: "+ticks);
                                timer = ticks = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The problem was in value of variable call FPS. When I set FPS in method call initRun() to 10, everything goes correctly. (simply thanks to method run() program wrote "FPS: 60" every second, and in frame was draw a rectangle).
But when I set FPS to (for example) 30, there was the problem. There was exception call "Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer" in render() method, concretely at instruction "canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);". 
[(image of exception)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuNlZ.jpg)
What can I do? Where is problem? I am not good in speaking english, so I don't understand this Exception and I don't know, what I can do...Please help me! Thanks.